# BIRT report dataset based on SP error

Tags: eclipse, dataset, report, birt

I have installed Eclipse IDE and create BIRT project. I've successfully added jdbc for MySQL connector and create a data source, which successfully passed.

When I create dataset that will rely on stored procedure I get an error that states:

> Cannot set preparedStatement parameter int value. SQL error #1:Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

I don't know why I am getting this error.

I execute my SP directly through MySQL Workbench like this way:

```
call getUserForCity(1);
```

and I got some results, around 100 rows. I've tried with hard-coded value and with parameter value separately and in both case I've got same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the catch, and also I would explain complete process of configuring dataset in BIRT.

After you successfully create data source to MySQL database, next step is creating a one or more datasets that rely on MySQL stored procedures.

On **Data Explorer** right click on **Dataset** and choose **New Dataset**. In dialog window, choose appropriate data source, give a name for dataset and choose one of two possible option for getting data from database: **Query** or **Stored procedure**.

Whatever option you choose, way of configuring parameters is same. In query editor write a code for calling stored procedure like this way:

```
call procedure_name(?, ?, ?, ...);
```

where number of '?' signs is related to number of parameters the procedure expecting.
On dataset configuration window choose **Parameters** option to define all parameters that your dataset accepts. Order of defined parameters must be same as order of stored procedure parameters or you can get error or unappropriate results.

Also, if you want to fill your dataset parameter with value of another parameter (often filled through another dataset) you can set this option in Parameter window choosing one of available parameter in section **Linked to Report Parameter**.

Comment: Hi! I noticed [this edit of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36173143/revisions). Please make sure that you only edit actual answers. That was clearly not an answer. It's wasted effort to polish poo, and edits on not-an-answer posts clear the not-an-answer flags on that post:) Let me know if you've read this, then I'll delete it (this was your newest answer, that's why I commented here).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the expected number of parameters for your stored procedure is 0 and instead of calling without parameters you are passing a parameter. You need either to modify your stored procedure to expect and handle the parameter or call it without paramters.

Comment: No, that is not the case, because my SP expects and accepts one parameter. By example, when I execute my SP in MySQL Workbench with `call getUserForCity(1);` I get 100 rows, so SP must accept one parameter.

Comment: @veljasije, are you sure you are calling the stored procedure you are talking about? Are you using the right database, etc.